# Missing divs yet appended

Tags: javascript, html

Why are the divs which contain the values from the subtasks array not added to the parent div? Even though the alert does work? The addsubtaskdiv(s) (child divs) must be appended to div3 (parent div).

```
div3=document.createElement('div');
div3.id="boxed";

subtasks = foodbudget.split(".");
for (x = 0; x < subtasks.length - 1; x++) {
    alert(subtasks[x]);
    addsubtaskdiv = document.createElement('div');
    //addsubtaskdiv.type="text";
    addsubtaskdiv.id = "subtask" + x;
    addsubtaskdiv.className = "cat1";
    addsubtaskdiv.innerHTML = subtasks[x];
    div3.appendChild(addsubtaskdiv);
}
```

Comment: And what does `foodbudget` contain? Also where are `subtasks` `addsubtaskdiv` & `div3` defined? You have multiple variables undefined... Please check your browser console for error reports.

Comment: How is the code above triggered?

Comment: triggered onload.foodbudget is a string  with the following data structure         value 1.value2.value3.the aim is to have these 3 values automatically split by  the full stop and then  create 3 divs and the value(between the dots) inserted in the divs automatically,no matter how many values are added to this string.

Comment: Can you update your source code and display how/where you're getting this string from and also display where your variables are defined? (Relevant source code) If you don't define your variables it will display the error in your browser console. Please check your console. Your browser console is your best friend when debugging javascript.

Comment: @user3672529 I understand what you wish to achieve and I can give you a working demo but I would like to see the rest of the relevant source code so I can explain why your current source code isn't working and in detail explain the changes I have made to make it work. I like people to learn from answers, not just copy/paste as you could be copy/pasting anything. It's always best to understand the code you place on your server.

Comment: Your code should work, so you need to add more context.

Comment: @epascarello even without defining the variables?

Comment: I defined two and it ran...

Comment: @epascarello But in the OP's source code I don't see them being defined and I also don't see `div3` targeting any element. That's what I'm trying to explain to him/her. Other than that, yes it should work just fine.

Comment: @NewToJS That is why I asked for more context.....

Comment: @user3672529, show code, where you appending `div3` to existing DOM element, If `div3` isn't appended to page DOM contents, then obviously it's childs also won't appear on the page